# Reading variables from PHP and performing a select query using js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I have this small project, and I'm trying to get the variables to my js file using ajax.

This is my js file:

```
function get_sites() {
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "server/newEmptyPHP1.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {type: "tasks"},
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
}
```

and this is my PHP file:

```
if (isset($_POST["type"])) {
    $type = $type = $_POST["type"];

    $returned_value = ""; //default value

    switch ($type) {
        case "tasks":
            $returned_value = display_tasks($conn);
            break;
    }
    $conn->close();
    echo $returned_value;
}

function display_tasks($conn) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Site`;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $html = "";
    $final_result = array();
    if ($result) {
        $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $row_count; ++$i) {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


            $task = array("id" => $row["ID"], "av" => $row["availability"], "lng" => $row["lng"], "lat" => $row["lat"]);

            $final_result["Site"][] = $task;
        }
    }
    print_r(json_encode($final_result));

    return json_encode($final_result);
}
```

The output:

```
{"Site":[{"id":"1","av":"1","lng":"16.963777","lat":"42.548664"},{"id":"2","av":"0","lng":"16.96376","lat":"42.548685"}]}
```

As you can see, this is the array I get from that PHP file, but I can't handle it well, so how can I get a variable in my js file from the previous array?

Comment: You are using `json` encoded data. Decode it before use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try JSON decode. Or for getting data in response you have to something like below:

```
...
success: function (data) {
    jQuery.each(data, function () {
        console.log(this);
        jQuery.each(this, function () {
            console.log("av=" + this.av + " --> id=" + this.id + " --> lat=" + this.lat + " --> lng=" + this.lng);
        });
    });
}
...
```

Comment: thank you a lot,
it works finally :')

Answer (score 0):

One approach using direct reference

JavaScript doesn't compulsorily require decoding json data as it can access the `json` data using direct object reference.

```
var data = {"Site":[{"id":"1","av":"1","lng":"16.963777","lat":"42.548664"},{"id":"2","av":"0","lng":"16.96376","lat":"42.548685"}]};


console.log(data.Site);
console.log(data.Site[0]);
console.log(data.Site[1]);

console.log(data.Site[0].id);
console.log(data.Site[0].av);
console.log(data.Site[0].lng);
console.log(data.Site[0].lat);

var data = data.Site; // you can avoid use capitals as in your output `Site`

for ( var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){

    var d = data[i];

    console.log('--------------------------');
    console.log(d);
    console.log(d.id);
    console.log(d.av);
    console.log(d.lng);
    console.log(d.lat);

}
```

> Its also supported without jQuery